# Passing query results to variable in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I have a SSIS package that runs a Execute SQL Task to get a row count, stores that in a variable, and then using a Script Task reads that variable and checks to see if it's greater than 0.

The issue I am having is that when I debug the package, it's reading the variable as -1 (which I assume is just SQL saying the query executed successfully), instead of the 38,000-some rows that are in the DB.
As far as I can tell, everything is set up correctly and coded the right way, so I'm not sure what could cause this.

**Execute SQL Task settings:**
[image]
[image]

**Code from Script Task:**
[image]

```
private byte[] emptyBytes = new byte[0];

    public void Main()
    {
        int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::SMART_rowcount"].Value.ToString());

        if (rowCount > 0)
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            Dts.Log("The SMART Row Count Check has failed due to result set having no rows. Check table SMART.[SMART_SEC_MGMT_QUOTE_DATA].", (int)Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure, emptyBytes);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

**Here is the flow of these and the variables:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please, to sort things out, add a screen of the flow with these two tasks as well as a screen with variables of the package?

Comment: @VladimirSemashkin They have been added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had everything set up correctly and there were no issues with my process. To resolve this error, I deleted the Execute SQL Task, remade it with all of the exact same settings and everything, and it is now returning the correct result.

"Have you tried turning it off and back on again?"

Answer (score 1):

In the `ResultSet` tab of your Execute SQL Task, you don't put the name of the column in the "Result Name" column.   You put the zero-based index of the column.

So instead of having "Smart_Count" under `Result Name`, you should have "0".

Comment: I've tried using 0, "0", and [0], but no form of trying to indicate the zero-based index has given me a different result. I still keep seeing -1 in the variable

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a script task for this but rather put an expression on the control flow.

@Smart_rowcount > 0 on main path.
and 
@Smart_rount<1 on the log path.

Comment: The Script Task isn't what's breaking here though, and I'm using it so that I can have detailed, custom logging. The issue is that the Execute SQL Task is storing the pass/fail indicator in the variable instead of the result of the COUNT statement